# How to change the 'continues on next page' table caption?

Tags: tables, pdftex, restructured-text

I am working on a user manual, compiling it from *.rst* source files with the *pdflatex* engine. My user manual has two versions: in English and in Russian. The issue that I have is connected with tables that take more than one page. I have 'continues on next page' and 'continued from the previous page' captions added automatically. These captions are not a problem in English. However, they are partially translated to Russian (the 'continues on next page' caption is left unchanged, see the images).

Is it possible to edit them or to remove them finally? I guess it might be defined in the preamble but I have no idea how to do this.

[image: captions in English version]

[image: captions in Russian version]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since you're asking for advice on how to modify some LaTeX code, it would really help if you provided the code that generates the current "look". Starting with the basics: Which document class and which TeX engine (pdftex, xetex, luatex, something else?) do you employ? Do you use `babel` or `polyglossia`? Which font families are in use? How are the tables that can span more than one page constructed? Ideally, you would post a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: If you are using longtable, the continued mesages are NOT automatic.  I don't know of any package which adds them automatically.  If you can find where they are being added, you should be able to change them.

Comment: I managed to take the .tex file from which a .pdf is build. Yes, I see there _longtable_ is used, and as @JohnKormylo proposed, I could find necessary strings and edit them. Thank you!